# Can I use Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio Community interchangeably for .NET CORE Web API

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

Please note that I am new to front-end and back-end Web API development.

I am not sure if this is possible, and I suspect it is not, but I am wondering if anyone knows whether or not it is possible to modify a .NET CORE Web API with both Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio Community? I suspect it is not because VS Community creates the project with a solution files whereas VS Code does not.

The reason for doing this is that I like the CLI nature of Visual Studio Code to create .NET CORE Web API's that can be developed in tandem with a EmberJS front-end framework. However, I much prefer Visual Studio Community's debugger and intellisense for more advanced development of the back-end. This is purely a preference and not necessarily a show stopper.

**Update:**

If it is possible, can you please provide the series of commands I would need to issue in order to create a `dotnet webapi` and add it to a `dotnet sln`?

**Update 2:**
The dotnet CLI website does not show how to add a `dotnet webapi` project template (with a corresponding solution file), which provides a base set of files to create the Web API. From what I can tell, we can add individual files (i.e., *.csproj). Is there a way to create a `dotnet webapi` project template with a corresponding solution file all at once; or do I have to either add each file manually in VS Code or just create a Web Api in VS Community and then work with it in VS Code?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln

Comment: Totally possible. You still need project files in vscode. Only sln are optional (but recommended). In full vs you can switch to directory mode instead of solution mode. Use can manage your sln file in vscode through `dotnet sln` command

Comment: @Kalten Oh sweet. Does the full VS support CLI commands?

Comment: Nothing forbidden you from opening a command prompt.

Comment: Most of the CLI stuff works via the Package Manager Console, since it's basically just PowerShell. However, it's not really designed for that, so it's still better to use an actual command prompt.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thank you two for your help! If you want to post the answer I will be happy to check it as the answer.

Comment: Have you tried testing if this works?

Comment: @Brad Not quite. I am able to create a solution, but how do I create a `dotnet new webapi` that is associated with the new solution? Or, should I just create the solution and project in VS Community and then run the `dotnet sln` commands from VS Code?

Comment: The point of my comment is for you to try it and find out.  You may find it is possible, therefore, have answered your own question.  If you get stuck then you can ask a more specific question to a problem that you're *actually* experiencing rather than asking a question for something you haven't even tried.

Comment: @Brad That's fair. I have updated the question to ask for the commands to create a new webapi and assign it to the solution. I believe from there I will have what I need.

Comment: @Brad Have you had a chance to look at the question? I hope you did not join in on the conversation just to lecture on what qualifies as a good question.

Comment: @JWeezy I refer you to my original question...have you tried testing if this works?  `dotnet sln --help`

Comment: @Brad There may be some miscommunication, apologies for any on my part. The dotnet CLI website does not show how to add a dotnet webapi `project` template, which provides a base set of files to create the web api. From what I can tell, we can add individual files (i.e., *.csproj). Is there a way to create a `dotnet webapi` project template with a corresponding solution file all at once; or do I have to either add each file manually or just create a WebApi in VS Community and then work with it from there in VS Code? Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q&A Style:

> I am not sure if this is possible, and I suspect it is not, but I am wondering if anyone knows whether or not it is possible to modify a .NET CORE Web API with both Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio Community?

It is possible. I use VSCode and vim on this: https://github.com/sillsdev/appbuilder-portal (which is a .netcore + React app)

> However, I much prefer Visual Studio Community's debugger and intellisense for more advanced development of the back-end.

VSCode has a .net core debugger and intellisense. you may need to install the C# extension.

> If it is possible, can you please provide the series of commands I would need to issue in order to create a dotnet webapi and add it to a dotnet sln?

`dotnet --help` can walk you through this, if you don't feel like looking up docs. Here are the docs though, if you want to bookmark this or somethin': https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln

```
dotnet sln add path/to/project.csproj
```

> Is there a way to create a dotnet webapi project template with a corresponding solution file all at once; or do I have to either add each file manually in VS Code or just create a Web Api in VS Community and then work with it in VS Code?

I think in the CLI, this needs to be multiple commands.

```
dotnet new webapi 
dotnet new sln
dotnet sln add *.csproj
```

hope this helps